# how to keep php output lines in one line

Tags: php, html, css

I just made a phone number to time zone converter and it displays result as:

```
Requested Phone No.: +1 732 78782722

Country: United States
```

Expected Region: Newark, New Brunswick

```
Timezone: America/New_York

Date: 2015-08-05

Time: 01:51:03 am
```

What I want to do is place all these outputs in a single line.
Here's my output code

```
      if(!empty($record['country_name'])) {
            $this->display('<strong>Country:</strong> ' . $record['country_name']);
        }

        if(!empty($record['city'])) {
            $this->display('<strong>Expected Region:</strong> ' . $record['city']);
        }

        //echo json_encode($date); 

        if(!empty($record['zone_name'])) {
            $this->display('<strong>Timezone:</strong> ' . $record['zone_name']);
            $this->display('<h2><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('Y-m-d') . '</h2>');
            $this->display('<h2><strong>Time:</strong> ' . date('H:i:s a') . '</h2>');
        }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you also show the code of display function you are using?

Comment: I think he is using Smarty

Answer (score 5):

Try this: If you want to pass that in a variable

```
if(!((empty($record['country_name']) && empty($record['city']) && empty($record['zone_name'])) {
    $var = '<strong>Country:</strong> ' . $record['country_name'] . '<strong>Expected Region:</strong> ' . $record['city'] .  '<strong>Timezone:</strong> ' . $record['zone_name']. '<h2><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('Y-m-d') . '</h2>' . '<h2><strong>Time:</strong> ' . date('H:i:s a') . '</h2>';
}

echo $var;
```

Or this if you want to pass in your object:

```
if(!((empty($record['country_name']) && empty($record['city']) && empty($record['zone_name'])) {
    $this->display('<strong>Country:</strong> ' . $record['country_name'] . '<strong>Expected Region:</strong> ' . $record['city'] .  '<strong>Timezone:</strong> ' . $record['zone_name']. '<h2><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('Y-m-d') . '</h2>' . '<h2><strong>Time:</strong> ' . date('H:i:s a') . '</h2>');
}

return $this;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a string variable and concatenate all your output to that string like below:-

```
$result = ''; // create an empty string

if(!empty($record['country_name']) && !empty($record['city']) && !empty($record['zone_name'])){

$result = '<strong>Country:</strong> ' . $record['country_name'].' <strong>Timezone:</strong> '. $record['city'].' <strong>Timezone:</strong> '.$record['zone_name'].' <h2><strong>Date:</strong> '. date('Y-m-d') . '</h2>'.' <h2><strong>Time:</strong> '. date('H:i:s a') . '</h2>';

}
echo $result; // print output
```

Comment: your post did help but problem is it has no spaces between the outputs @AK-Sonu

Comment: You can use `&nbsp;` for this purpose.